# All Possible Matching Lists

Tags: code-golf, array

Implement a function that takes a list that consists of 0, 1 or 2, the list is called "pattern". Your job is to return all possible lists that match the pattern.

- 0 matches 0
- 1 matches 1
- 2 matches 0 and 1

Examples:

```
f([0, 1, 1]) == [[0, 1, 1]]
f([0, 2, 0, 2]) == [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
f([2, 1, 0]) == [[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
```

Order does not matter, you can use a {set} data structure instead.

You cannot use regular expressions or other **string** pattern matching mechanisms. You cannot use a brute-force search.

Shortest solution wins.

Comment: How do you define a brute force search?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Haskell, 49 characters

```
f[]=[[]]
f(2:r)=f(0:r)++f(1:r)
f(x:r)=map(x:)$f r
```

Interestingly this is exactly what I'd write even if this wasn't golf - except for removing spaces and calling the list's tail `r` rather than `xs`.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>34</s> 26 characters

Saved 8 characters thanks to Zgarb.

```
r 2=[0,1]
r n=[n]
f=mapM r
```

Comment: `sequence.map` is equivalent to `mapM`, which is 8 characters shorter.

Answer (score 5):

## Prolog, 62 characters

```
f([],[]). f([H|T],[A|B]):-((H=2,(A=0;A=1));(H<2,A=H)),f(T,B).
```

Example:

```
?- f([0,2,0,2],X).
X = [0, 0, 0, 0] ;
X = [0, 0, 0, 1] ;
X = [0, 1, 0, 0] ;
X = [0, 1, 0, 1] ;
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 30 chars

```
f=Tuples[{#}&/@#/.{2}->{0,1}]&
```

Examples:

```
f[{0, 1, 1}]
```

> {{0, 1, 1}}

```
f[{0, 2, 0, 2}]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}

```
f[{2, 1, 0}]
```

> {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}

Comment: Since the OP isn't asking for a named function you can even drop the `f=`.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby - 76 characters

```
def f l;l==l-[2]?[l]:((j=l.dup)[k=l.index(2)]=0;(i=l.dup)[k]=1;f(j)+f(i))end
```

#### Testing script:

```
require_relative 'golf-lists'

[
  [0, 1, 1],
  [0, 2, 0, 2],
  [2, 1, 0]
].each do |list|
  puts "f([#{list.join(', ')}]) == #{f(list)}"
end
```

Result:

```
f([0, 1, 1]) == [[0, 1, 1]]
f([0, 2, 0, 2]) == [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
f([2, 1, 0]) == [[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Scheme <strike>(149)</strike> (148)

```
(define(f l)(if(null? l)'(())(let((t(f(cdr l)))(n(car l)))(if(< n 2)(map(lambda(m)`(,n,@m))t)`(,@(map(lambda(m)`(0,@m))t),@(map(lambda(m)`(1,@m))t]
```

With whitespace (the closing square brace closes all open parentheses on certain Scheme implementations; 154 chars without it):

```
(define (f l)
  (if (null? l)
      '(())
      (let ((t (f (cdr l)))(n(car l)))
        (if (< n 2)
            (map (lambda (m) `(,n ,@m)) t)
            `(,@(map (lambda (m) `(0 ,@m)) t)
              ,@(map (lambda (m) `(1 ,@m)) t]
```

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 18 bytes

CJam is much younger than this challenge, so this is answer is not eligible for being accepted.

```
]]l~{2b\f{\f+~}}/p
```

Reads input from STDIN as a CJam style array.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5D%5Dl~%7B2b%5Cf%7B%5Cf%2B~%7D%7D%2Fp&input=%5B0%202%201%202%5D)

### Explanation

```
]]l~{2b\f{\f+~}}/p
]]                 "Push a nested empty array [[]] onto the stack. This is the base case.";
  l~               "Read and eval the input.";
    {          }/  "For each integer in the input.";
     2b            "Convert to base 2. This turns 0 into [0], 1 into [1] and 2 into [1 0].";
       \f{    }    "Swap with the current result and map this block onto the base-2 representation
                    copying in the current list of lists on each iteration.";
          \f+      "Swap the list of lists with the 0 or 1 and add the number to each list.";
             ~     "Unwrap the list of lists. They'll be regrouped by the surrounding f{...}.";
                 p "Pretty-print the result.";
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 156 bytes

```python
def f(l):R,L=range(len(l)),[];exec"\n".join(" "*j+"for v%d in[[l[%d]],[0,1]][l[%d]>1]:"%(j,j,j)for j in R)+"L+=["+"".join("v%d,"%j for j in R)+"],";return L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY7BasMwDIbvewohCNiLKXWOLekThB16dXUoi7PFBLsoXmmfPnUbb5CNwSYL49/6@fSfrvE9@GqaWttBJwa52aum5qN/s2KwPn1IZWhrL/YVDx5XLvReIOCzK7ELDOeihd4bM5iiJVJmrTTRrHaaNlgIp9KRd69LTtjLEpuyNljiJy0xFBYOFh5SuGUbP9hDMx3H0XJM@RIfdGqSkKquYQwcbSvAfE0I/lXyaQGvFNzvxP8Oz00K8qofSme1zooW8Gq2/Zr8wdL5SX9KfuLeR8CXAPOaPniwzIFXON0A)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 19 bytes

```
[:>@,[:{{&(0;1;0 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/6Ot7Bx0oq2qq9U0DKwNrQ0UDDX/a3Ip6Smop9laqSvoKNRaKaQVc3GlJmfkK6QpGAG1ATGCa6hg@B8A)

I had originally created a much longer version using amend and binary numbers, but user b_jonas suggested the above approach in IRC to me.

It essentially converts 0 and 1 to themselves, and 2 to the list `0 1`, and the just cross products everything using catalog `{`.  Since catalog requires boxed data, and returns structured data, everything is (un)raveled and unboxed at the end: `>@,`.